# R call stack detailed inspection

Tags: r, callstack, magrittr

I'm looking for correct way to go with call stack logging.
I have functions, which logs their calls to list.

```r
s <- list()
f <- function(){
  s <<- c(s,list(sys.call()))
  g()
}
g <- function(){
  s <<- c(s,list(sys.call()))
  1
}
```

They will be called in unknown sequence.

```r
f()
f()
g()
f()
```

What data should I log besides of `sys.call()` to be able to build call hierarchy?
I would like to change my current log granularity.

```r
sapply(s,deparse)
# [1] "f()" "g()" "f()" "g()" "g()" "f()" "g()"
```

To something like below.

```r
#    sys.call call_id call_seq
#  :      f()       1        0
#  :      g()       1        1
#  :      f()       2        0
#  :      g()       2        1
#  :      g()       3        0
#  :      f()       4        0
#  :      g()       4        1
```

Having data in such granularity I would be able to rebuild hierarchy of calls.

Thanks

Comment: How about using `sys.calls()` at all end-leaf calls

Comment: @xingzhi.sg don't know end-leaf calls. The `f` might call `g` only on specific condition. So `f` can be leaf too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to manage that process.
On each call I measure recursive depth of the call chain. Using call depth and calls order I've calc the single call chains.
The part of code which solved the problem is *kind of*:

```
dt[, seq := depth( call_chain )
   ][, id := cumsum( seq==1L ) ]
```

For complete case [this](https://github.com/jangorecki/dtq/blob/bde12cc3caecae3b24a06d43038fd5739716db51/R/dtq.R#L62).